# Pagination For Custom Query Is Not Working

Tags: wordpress

I am creating a custom homepage template in which I am trying to show posts with navigation.

Here is what I have followed.

1. Created a file homepage.php and gave the template name as "HomePage".
2. Created a page "Home" from dashboard and assigned this template "HomePage".
3. Then from settings > reading, chosen static front page "Home".

Here is my code for querying posts.

```
  <div class="posts-container">
    <?php query_posts('post_type=post&posts_per_page=2&post_status=publish&paged='. get_query_var('paged')); ?>
     <?php if(have_posts()): ?>
      <?php while (have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <div class="post"> 
          <h4 class="entry-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>
          </div>
      <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
   </div>

    <div class="pagination-nav">
     <div class="alignleft"><?php next_posts_link(__('Next »','example')); ?></div>
     <div class="alignright"><?php previous_posts_link(__('« Previous','example')); ?></div>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Now, on clicking the links generated by pagination functions, I am getting redirected to the page where I was first. While the URL gets updated like

> http://localhost/mysite/?paged=2

Lets say if there are 4 posts (post 1, post 2, post 3, post 4) that and the recent ones are post 4 and post 3 respectively, then I cannot get to post 1 and post 2. Both of the pages

> http://localhost/mysite
>   http://localhost/mysite/?paged=2

show me only the post 4 and post 3. What can I do to solve this?

Comment: Don't use `query_posts`. It breaks the main query and pagination

Answer (score 0):

For a [static front page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination#static_front_page) you need to check for the `page` var too, in this way:

```
if ( get_query_var('paged') ) { $paged = get_query_var('paged'); }
elseif ( get_query_var('page') ) { $paged = get_query_var('page'); }
else { $paged = 1; }

query_posts('...&paged=' . $paged);
```

Answer (score 0):

This was the solution that worked for me. I had to re-write the query and have used WP Query this time.

```
  <?php 
   global $wp_query, $paged; 
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

    $query_args = array (
          'post_type' => 'post',
          'post_status'=>'publish',
          'posts_per_page' => 4,      //for testing purposes
          'paged' => $paged,
    );

    $wp_query = new WP_Query($query_args);

if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) :
   while ( $wp_query->have_posts()) :
         $wp_query->the_post();
  ?>
<div class="post">
  <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
  <a class="entry-image" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
  <?php the_post_thumbnail(); } ?>
  </a>
  <h4 class="entry-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
    <?php the_title(); ?>
    </a></h4>
  <div class="entry">
    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
  </div>
</div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<div class="pagination-nav">
  <div class="alignleft">
    <?php next_posts_link(__('Oudere artikelen')); ?>
  </div>
  <div class="alignright">
    <?php previous_posts_link(__('Newer')); ?>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /posts-container -->
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

And Whola!, this one worked. 
Might be useful for someone else.